# How Can i address theme in other solution in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, exception, resourcedictionary

I have a project with several solutions. In my core solution, i have a theme folder that contains my themes. In shell solution and `App.xaml` file I wanna to address my themes. like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Hezareh.Core;component/Themes/CustomDocumentViewerTemplate.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Hezareh.Core;component/Themes/Darkness.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Hezareh.Core;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

But i receive this error :

> Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myself find a solution for this problem.

for solve this problem we should right click on theme file  and click properties.

on properties window most set Build action to page.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code like this :

```
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Hezareh.Core;component/Themes/CustomDocumentViewerTemplate.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Hezareh.Core;component/Themes/Darkness.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Hezareh.Core;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Comment: dear Niki Nikpour. i still receive this error "Cannot locate resource 'themes/customdocumentviewertemplate.xaml'."